# Mongodump for Daily Backups

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am considering using mongodump for daily backups.

If I always perform the dump on the same directory: do I have to make sure to clear the contents from the previous day, before running mongodump? I could not find anything about this in the documentation.

Comment: With everything already set up: Why didn't you try it out?

Comment: @ppeterka: because I would not trust the success of the backup method on a simple test; I would rather also have confirmation by people with experience.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, mongodump will overwrite any contents in the directory, so you're safe to use the same one.

Comment: Confirmed:  "[mongodump overwrites output files if they exist in the backup data folder](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#behavior)"